# Mac Catalyst version

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, mac-catalyst

I wonder what does macCatalyst version means and how it is mapped to macOS version? For example, API which is available from `macCatalyst 14.0` means it requires `macOS 11.0` (Big Sur), `macCatalyst 13.0` means `macOS 10.15.0`, but what does it mean when API required minimal target `macCatalyst 13.4`? To what version of macOS it correspond?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I haven't found an official list or a way to pull the macOS version from code. I think `UIDevice.current.systemVersion` used to return the macOS version, but now it returns the macCatalyst version. That makes it hard to support users who know their macOS version but have no idea what the embedded macCatalyst version is.

Building on the previous posts and my own observations, here's a partial list:

```
macCatalyst 13.0 = macOS 10.15 (Catalina)
macCatalyst 13.4 = macOS 10.15.4
macCatalyst 14.0 = macOS 11.0 (Big Sur)
macCatalyst 14.7 = macOS 11.6
macCatalyst 15.0 = macOS 12.0 (Monterey)
macCatalyst 15.3 = macOS 12.2 and 12.2.1
macCatalyst 15.4 = macOS 12.3
macCatalyst 15.5 = macOS 12.4
macCatalyst 15.6 = macOS 12.5
macCatalyst 16.6 = macOS 13.5 (Ventura)
macCatalyst 17.0 = macOS 14.0 (Sonoma)
macCatalyst 17.2 = macOS 14.2 and 14.2.1
```

Comment: For those wondering, Mac Catalyst versions are almost always the same as iOS versions, with a few exceptions at the introduction. Therefore, if your project can be deployed to iOS 15.0+, it means it can be deployed to Mac Catalyst 15.0+ as well. Find the corresponding macOS and Xcode building requirements at https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/

Comment: Mac Catalyst 16.x = macOS 13.x and 17.x = macOS 14.x

Answer (score 9):

The Mac Catalyst version is usually the same as the iOS version. The corresponding minimum macOS version can be found in the same documentation page as follows:

[image]

So, I'd just suggest checking the online docs page for the feature/API you're trying to use to figure out the minimum macOS version.

Comment: It doesn't show the macOS version now in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you supplied, macCatalyst 13.4 corresponds to macOS 10.15.4.