# [macOS cocoa]issue of building the project of Mac Catalyst Tutorials

Tags: xcode, cocoa

[Mac Catalyst Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/mac-catalyst) is a tutorial from Apple official site. I tried to build the project named Recipes from this website. However, it was built faild and shows "'authorizationStatus(for:)' is only available in Mac Catalyst 14.0 or newer" [image: figure]
I lerned that Mac Catalyst 14.0 means macOS 11.0 from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69748714/16783850). So I checked this interface [image: figure] but found no version settings about macOS. Then I checked this interface [image: figure] and found the version of macOS is correct. However, I trid again buildiing the project but the issue is still "'authorizationStatus(for:)' is only available in Mac Catalyst 14.0 or newer". Please tell me what's the reason and how to deal with it.